# Bash for loop does run forever

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I build a script to send me notifications after a certain amount of time.
Here's the part which doesn't work (will highlight important stuff later):

```
if [[ $choice == "-c" ]]
then

  timer=$2
  if [[ $5 == "-m" ]]
  then
    timer=$(( $2 * 60 ))
  fi
  echo $timer

  if [[ $5 == "-h" ]]
  then
    timer=$(( $2 * 3600 ))
  fi

  echo "Notification will be send in:" $timer "Second(s)"
  for (( index = 0; index < $timer; index++ ))
  do
    sleep 1
  done
  notify-send -t $time $msg
fi
```

I call the script with

```
./scriptname <type> <time it should run> [message] [set the time to m/h]
```

The type doesn't matter here because it executes the correct if block.
The time it should run is how long it waits till the notification is send.
The set the time to m/h is a simple parameter. If i give nothing in here the time will be given in seconds (it always is but the user input isn't changed).

Okay so.
The `$msg` variable contains the message which will get send.
`$2`is the time input. 
`$choice` is not really important all it does is select the correct code to execute (and the programs comes in this if statement)
`$5` contains either '-m' or '-h' (nothing is also an option) and then the `$timer` variable gets increased by the following.

The problem is that if i want to have it in minutes (for what the "-m" stands). The program will execute this statement:

```
if [[ $5 == "-m" ]]
then
  timer=$(( $2 * 60 ))
fi
```

With the `echo $timer` I know that it worked but the problem I got is that the script doesn't stop running. It runs perfectly when I just execute it with the given input. (So the program doesn't go into any if statements for the `$timer` variable.) But if I say that the time should be treated as minutes or hours (just tested with minutes) it doesn't work, or to be more correct it just doesn't override the `$timer` variable
Does anybody know why?

EDIT:
I totally forgot that I implemented at $4 an time on which the message gets shown. I forgot that totally so I actually call the script with.

```
./scriptname <type> <time it should run> [message] [time the message gets shown] [set time to m/h]
```

And yes I don't need the forloop. I can just make it with `sleep $timer`

Comment: Why don't you use `sleep` to its full extent? `sleep 5m` will sleep 5 minutes. No loops, no awkward parameter parsing...

Comment: Is your script also named `sleep`?

Comment: Why are you looping instead of using `sleep $timer`? You can spawn `sleep` once or $timer times.

Comment: For using options, I'd recommend `getopts` -- then you're not forcing your users to enter options in a particular order.

Comment: After you edited my answer is no longer helpful. I will delete it. Then you should rebuild the question so the right command is where it belongs (not as an erratum at the end). `it just doesn't override the $timer variable` – Is this still valid? I thought I solved just this. Is the current problem `the script doesn't stop running` only? If so, rebuild the question even more. In general you shouldn't invalidate answers (upvoted answers!) by changing the question but in this case I support this as the author of the only answer so far.

Comment: Did you check what `$2` / `$timer` looks like after you do the multiplication?

Comment: @Seth yes it checked it but if you read the edit you will see that i figured out the problem